# URL Rewriting in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting, glassfish-3

I am using Glassfish 3.1(For windows) to deploy/test Web-apps on localhost. Now i want to use URL Rewriting.

URL Rewriting is must for me as My website contains more than 500 products listed in database..

Currently I am using below URL(Dynamic) to get product details from database..

http://localhost:8080/PRODUCTS/List_product.action?productId=345627

I want to change the above URL like this...

http://localhost:8080/PRODUCTS/List_product.action/productId/345627/Intelligent-Calculator

I know Search engine likes Static pages more than Dynamic ones & there are great advantages using static URL's like high Ranking & 
PR.

I am using Struts2 Frameork.. for my web-app

I have also heard about .htaccess file but not sure about this

I am in trouble now.... Please help me Guys...Thanks in advance...Suggestions are welcomed...

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library  available for this requirement, check out [pretty faces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)

Comment: not sure which web-framework you are using , and it is compatible with it or not .

Comment: I am using Struts2 Framework. I am sure that it is supported on Glassfish 3.1

Comment: check out pretty faces if it is integratable with struts